# Method inheritance in immutable classes

Tags: scala, design-patterns, inheritance, traits

I am stumbling on something that I hope is a bit of a basic issue. Probably its because I am new to Scala, and probably I am still missing some important concepts.

I am trying to program in an FP fashion, and data classes which do not need to have a mutable state are immutable, with some transformation methods to create new objects to update them if needed. However, I am struggling when it comes to maintaining the return types of this method when I have traits and general inheritance in place. I wish to avoid messy type casts or things like that as much as possible, because this is still a learning experience for me.

See this example here, where I have an immutable class extending some trait. The `update` method is intended to change the data, call some method of the actual class (which is abstract in the trait) and return a new instance of the same class updated to the new data. One could map this roughly to the Template pattern.

```
trait MyTrait
{
   val someDataVal : Integer;

   def update(newDataVal) : MyTrait = {
     //some logic takes place here, which is common

     abstractUpdate(newDataVal)
   }

   //some logic takes place, specific to the implementation class
   def abstractUpdate(newDataVal : Integer) : MyTrait
}


class MyClass(dataVal : Integer) extends MyTrait
{
   override val someDataVal = dataVal

   def abstractUpdate(newDataVal : Integer) : MyClass = {
     //some class specific logic here ........

     MyClass(newDataVal)
   }

   def someOtherFunction() : Integer = { 
     //some logic here .....
   }
 }
```

I obviously do not wish to copy and paste `update()` into `MyClass` I want it to stay in the trait so that I can use it by any class extending it. However if I try to call it, what I get is an object of type `MyTrait`, and so I cannot call `someOtherFunction()` on it.

What is the right Scala approach to achieve this kind of OO reuse and still have my code clean?

**UPDATE**

Please take note of the places where I put `//some logic takes place here`, that means I might have some code there which I want to be centralised in the trait and not copied and pasted in each concrete class extending it. This is just a skeleton to illustrate the problem. Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE**

Code example based on the answer provided by wheaties. The issue is with the `return this`.

```
trait MyTrait[T <: MyTrait[T]]{
  def update(newValue: Int): T = {
    if (newValue == 0)
      return this;  //this creates a type mismatch
    else
      concreteUpdate(newValue)
  }

  def concreteUpdate(value : Int) : T
}

class MyClass(value: Int) extends MyTrait[MyClass]
{
  override def concreteUpdate(value : Int) = new MyClass(value)
}
```

Comment: There are multiple options, the Scala collections could be an inspiration: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html you can also try typeclasses. Probably case classes copy method might also help implementing the update.

Comment: @GáborBakos Thanks for your comment. I am still a bit confused about how it is working in collections. Regarding the update, that is just skeleton code to illustrate the issue in the most minimal way possible. My question is about handling this type inheritance when modifying immutable objects (i.e. creating new instances of the same types with different data)

Answer (score 3):

I've answered a similar question before and the comment by @GaborBakos is spot on. If you'd like to be able to do similar things to what you might find with the `map` method of `TraverseableLike` then you need to do the following:

```
trait MyTrait[T <: MyTrait[T]]{
  def update(newValue: Int): T
}
```

which basically is a type definition which depends on itself! Hence, the return type of `update` is `T`. Then:

```
class MyClass(value: Int) extends MyTrait[MyClass]{
  def update(newValue: Int) = new MyClass(newValue)
}
```

which should work since `T` is `MyClass`.

**Side Note:**

Don't put `val` in a trait. Instead, make it a `def`. That way, you don't run into initialization ordering issues with anyone that wants to extend your class. If you don't follow this advice, then you can run into situations where a very NOT `null` field is being treated as a `null`.

Comment: I feel that avoiding `val` in favour of `def` is an anti-solution that trades away stable identifiers, and that early initialisation blocks are a better solution.

Comment: @wheaties Thanks for your reply. However it does not seem to be doing what I need. You did not put the code I need to have in common in the trait and just moved it to the concrete class, i.e. if I have 10 classes extending that trait I will have to copy and paste the same code 10 times into the concrete classes. I've separated them in 2 methods and put the comment `some logic takes place here...` on purpose to illustrate this.

Comment: @wheaties Regarding your side note on `val` versus `def`, what if I have a value which is expensive to compute and I just want to compute it once and reuse it?

Comment: @jbx Couple comments: 1. You can always put the logic in the trait. There's nothing wrong with doing that nor would this preclude it. 2. Anything that is a `def` can be made a `val` in an inheriting class/trait. Really! That's the best part of traits.

Comment: @wheaties Re 2. Oh, didn't know they were interchangeable that way. Re 1. So how would I go about it in the example you presented? Some logic needs to take place in common (in the trait) which calls the specific methods of the extending class. For instance, in my case I have a `List` of values as one of the constructor arguments, and what my updating function is goes through them and changes them to something else. This logic is exactly the same for all extending classes, so it would make sense to be in the `trait`, but the return type has to be different to match each concrete class.

Comment: @wheaties So I tried some more to do it as you indicated. The only problem I have now is that in certain cases `update()` returns the same object (when there is no need to update anything). Since `update`  returns `T`, when I try to return `this` I am getting the error that `MyTrait[T]` doesn't conform to expected type `T`.

Comment: @jbx You'll have to show some code. There's a number of things you could be doing wrong.

Comment: @wheaties OK. I've updated my question with your code and with the extra parts to illustrate my problem. The dummy example returns the same instance if the value is 0 rather than a new instance.

Comment: @jbx I see the issue. `this` at the trait level is `MyTrait[T]` not `T`. Perhaps try using a self type, i.e. put `self: T =>` in the trait and then return `self`. I say try because I'm not in front of a Scala compiler.

Comment: @wheaties Oh after a bit of searching I got what you meant. Still I don't have the faintest idea what this occult `self : T =>` put in the trait means, but it seems to do the magic. And I don't even have to return `self`, suddenly `this` was accepted. The problem I have now however is that I had another class which took the trait as argument type, and I patterned matched on it to check for a specific concrete class. Now it stopped working because of the `[T]`. I cannot have `MyTrait` as an argument anymore it seems.

Comment: This approach doesn't quite work. While it achieves the return type problem when updating, we lose the whole point of inheritance and polymorphism. I cannot have a function in another class that takes `MyTrait` as an argument now, because it needs to somehow know the type beforehand.